# How to run django views.function() on everyday midnight 00:00 using scheduler or schedu

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, scheduler, apscheduler

```
## below  created  scd.py
import schedule
import time 

from .views import *

# Create your tests here.

def job():
    views.attendancetemplate()
    #a= urllib.request.urlopen(url='http://172.16.1.100:8000/tmp', ) ## this is working but still `enter code here`
    print("I'm working...")




schedule.every().day.at("20:23").do(job)
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)


#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#       THIS IS Views.py
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
from django.contrib.auth.backends import UserModel
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in, user_login_failed
from django.shortcuts import render , redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib import messages
from schedule import every
from . import views
from .models import *
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, get_user, login ,get_user_model, update_session_auth_hash
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from datetime import date
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordChangeForm
from datetime import timedelta
import csv
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import permission_required

import schedule
import time
enter image description here

#########################################################################################################
## ****************!IMPORTANT ********************** USER TEMPLATE
```

#########################################################################################################
def attendancetemplate(request):
today = datetime.date.today()
x=datetime.datetime.now()
ldate= Attendance.objects.order_by('id').last()
ldate1=ldate.date
yesterday = today - timedelta(days = 1)
prev = today - timedelta(days = 2)
# if ldate1 == yesterday:
User1 = get_user_model()
users = User1.objects.all()
for i in users:
uname = i.username
iname = i.first_name
ausr =Attendance(User_Name = uname,date =today,Name=iname)
ausr.save()

```
      if i is None:
       break
      print("I'm working...")


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciyLW.png
```

Comment: Please help to correct the format code!

Comment: It's not possible since too little text is provided.

Comment: Marco  I want to create a user list on database ever day midnight using VIEWs. so. Here my question if I use schedule in sperate file and u call a views. Function () but not working , @Marco

Comment: @Vu Phan attendance template is function to create a user details on database when ever you call this function

Comment: Scd.py where. Schedule loop created to call attendance template ().

Comment: @THIRUMALAIVASAN K can you format the code in your post?